# access android global setting via code

Tags: android

i am working on a simple home launcher, but a cant find a way to access global android setting like wireless,application etc, i've alredy read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html but couldnt find the answer,please someone tell me how to do that, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Be more clear in the question. What do you mean when you talk about Global Settings? Be Specific.

Comment: its standart setting like when at home screen we press menu button and then press setting,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. You read android's [src code](http://android.git.kernel.org/) and you check `which` intent is sent.
2. Go to the setting menu you are looking and check in `Logcat` which intent is used.